# Set a property to null with Google Cloud Dataflow's Java API for Datastore?

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

The `com.google.cloud.datastore` package mentioned in most of Google's Java documentation for Datastore provides a Builder class with a `setNull` method used to set any property value to `null`, e.g.

```
FullEntity.Builder<IncompleteKey> builder = FullEntity.newBuilder();
builder.setNull("propertyName");
```

Google Cloud Dataflow/Apache Beam's DatastoreIO class requires Entities in the package `com.google.datastore.v1`, and the builder methods do not include a similar `setNull` method. How do I set a property to `null` using the V1 Java APIs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using the `com.google.datastore.v1` package Entity and Value, this is how to set a null value (with Apache Beam/Google Dataflow):

```
import com.google.datastore.v1.Entity;
import com.google.datastore.v1.Entity.Builder;
import com.google.datastore.v1.Value;
import com.google.protobuf.NullValue;

Value nullValue = Value.newBuilder().setNullValue(NullValue.NULL_VALUE).build();
Entity.Builder builder = Entity.newBuilder();
builder.putProperties("propertyName", nullValue);
```

(Answering my own question since it took me quite a while to figure this out!)